# cakephp helper call function of other helper

Tags: cakephp, cakephp-3.0

what i am trying to achieve is to automate helpers loading scripts and css.
So basically the idea is to have a function on every helper, which is loading scripts / styles to be used dedicated to the helper.
I guess it can be achieved by having a controlling helper which is querying for all active helpers and then execute the script/style loading function.

What I cannot find in the documentation is:

- How can a helper query the list of active helper objects

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can query the [`HelperRegistry`](http://api.cakephp.org/3.2/class-Cake.View.HelperRegistry.html) of the `View` using (see [`View::helpers`](http://api.cakephp.org/3.2/class-Cake.View.View.html#_helpers)):

```
$this->_View->helpers();
```

Once you have the registry, you can get the names of the loaded helper using [`HelperRegistry::loaded()`](http://api.cakephp.org/3.2/class-Cake.View.HelperRegistry.html#_loaded) and retrieve them using [`HelperRegistry::get()`](http://api.cakephp.org/3.2/class-Cake.View.HelperRegistry.html#_get):

```
// Inside your helper:
$registry = $this->_View->helpers();
foreach ($registry->loaded() as $name) {
    $helper = $registry->get($name);
}
```

*Disclaimer: Code above not tested.*